# WinForms dialogs with TopMost = true

Tags: winforms, dialog

I have a dialog implemented in WinForms that is shown as a notify dialog on the bottom right of the screen. The problem is that whenever is shown it takes the focus and this happens only when TopMost = true. How can I solve this?

Comment: TopMost = false;? or was that to easy to say :D

Comment: To easy to say. My customer wants it TopMost = true.

Comment: So you want a dialog on top but without focus? Sorta messenger popup for new mail?

Comment: Yes, exactly like a messenger popup.

Comment: A note about showing the notification on the bottom right of the screen: I *really* hate when apps assume that the TNA is in the bottom right corner of the primary screen. My taskbar is on the left side of the primary screen (TNA bottom left) - showing the notification in the bottom left corner of the primary screen, or on the bottom right corner of the secondary screen would be the right thing to do, but most apps get it wrong. So, either make it like Outlook 2007 (make the notification window movable in preferences) or have some options. At least, consider the *desktop* area, not a *screen*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inherit from Form and override a couple of properties:

```
[Flags]
enum WS_EX
{
    TOPMOST = 0x00000008,
}

class TopMostForm : Form
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            var baseParams = base.CreateParams;
            baseParams.ExStyle |= (int)WS_EX.TOPMOST;
            return baseParams;
        }
    }

    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Then just simply Show() on this form and it will be displayed as topmost and inactive.

Comment: It does not work if TopMost=true. Works only when TopMost=false.

Comment: Ups, I think it is shown TopMost even if TopMost=false. Right?

Comment: Window style WS_EX_TOPMOST makes your window top-most. If you look at `Form.TopMost` property in Reflector, you'll see that it uses different approach that makes your window active.

Answer (score 1):

Show the dialog with Show instead of ShowDialog.
ShowDialog will be topmost, user has to click it before doing something else (modal)
Show will show it as normal.

Answer (score 0):

How about this strategy:

1. Show it at startup, then immediately:
2. Hide it with [ShowWindow](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.ShowWindow)( SW_HIDE )
3. Never ever close the form, just let it be invisible
4. Show it with ShowWindow( SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE )