# How to show non-interactive, auto-hiding notification popup message with Windows Forms in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Using Windows Forms, .NET 3.5 framework, language: c#
I would like to show a popup window for 1 second to notify users of actions that are performed. For example, when I copy a file X I want to show a notification like "Copied file X to File X-copy". Should be shown for a second, then autohide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispite the answers given. I think a message that pops up is somewhat *not* user friendly. What about using a statusbar [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.statusbar%28VS.85%29.aspx)? It's not that evasive (and you can show the progress)

Comment: Maybe the app he's building rarely raises these popups (thinking of Dropbox), maybe the main UI isn't visible, etc...

Comment: Ofcourse the statusbar can't be used for all messages. But thinking of a different approach is sometimes better :)

Comment: I think you are right, using the statusbar is the best approach and in line with the behaviour of the host application I am creating an add-in for (Visual Studio). Thank for getting me back to senses:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer. Something along the lines of the following where ShowFloating does the initial display and HideFloating does, you know.

```
public void ShowFloatingForXMilliSeconds(int milliSeconds) {
    ShowFloating();
    if (_autoOffTimer == null) {
        _autoOffTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _autoOffTimer.Elapsed += OnAutoOffTimerElapsed;
        _autoOffTimer.SynchronizingObject = this;
    }
    _autoOffTimer.Interval = milliSeconds;
    _autoOffTimer.Enabled = true;
}

void OnAutoOffTimerElapsed(Object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs ea) {
    if ((_autoOffTimer != null) && _autoOffTimer.Enabled) {
        _autoOffTimer.Enabled = false;
        HideFloating();
    }
}
```

Also detach the timer handler and dispose the timer in Dispose.

Comment: Although I would add that if you can find a control in the gui framework you are using, that does what you want, then use that. There wasn't anything in winforms for us.

Answer (score 1):

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727789/winforms-dialogs-with-topmost-true/1728171#1728171) will help you to make topmost window without stealing focus from currently active window.

To complete your solution, in simple case you need to add a timer on your form to make sure the form auto-closes after 1 second and locate your notification window properly (you probably want it in the bottom right part of the screen? - that's a simple arithmetic exercise).

For more advanced solution, you should create NotificationManager class and manage lifetime of your notification message forms there.